# Firestore document is not getting deleted

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete document before saving new data on same document snapshot id, but `delete()` function seems to have no effect. I can add new data to child `collection` of same document.
The current user(only user) has write permission. Complete write rule is shown below -

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth!=null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == "removed-for-security-reason";
    }
  }
}
```

Code to delete document -

```
fun saveUserLanguage(languages: ArrayList<NELanguage>, success : () -> Unit, error: () -> Unit){
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val userRef = db.collection("user_language").document(user!!.uid)
    
    userRef.delete()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
       // the following works
       val userLanguageRef = userRef.collection("data")
        db.runBatch {batch ->
          languages.forEach {
            batch.set(userLanguageRef.document(it.id), it)
          }
       }.addOnSuccessListener {
         success()
       }.addOnFailureListener {
         error()
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the structure of your Firestore database (from what I could see in the question):

```
user_language       // Root collection
  doc1              // Document
    data            // Data subcollection
      somedoc       // Subcollection documents
      anotherdoc
```

When a document in the root collection (**doc1**) has a subcollection and you call the delete method on it the following happens:

- The document won't appear in queries or snapshots. i.e: `db.collection('user_language').get()` results won't include **doc1**.
- The document will still be visible from the Firestore Console UI
- The subcollection **data** and it's documents are not deleted.

So, while the document is indeed being deleted, it may not appear like so if you check the Console UI. Nonetheless you would see that the document doesn't have any fields. This behavior is documented under "Delete data" from the Firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#kotlin+ktx).

in case what you want to achieve is to delete the document as well as the subcollections I would suggest checking the following [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) which offers some code samples and best practices to that regard.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I just saw the doc. properly. Initially, I thought  delete means document and it's sub collections will be removed. But here it's just that it will only hide the document from query. I think it would better and less confusing if `delete` method name changed to something like `fakeDelete`.